# Populate JQuery DataTable With JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've got what I Think is an array of objects like this `console.log` shows

```
Array(39) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
0: Object { Name: "Jason", Grade: 12 }
```

What code should I use to format it so that the jQuery datatable will let me set this as the source?

https://datatables.net/

I tried to do this, but it gives me an error:

```
    $.myjQuery = function(testData) {
      $('#example').DataTable({
        data: testData,
        columns: [
          { title: 'Name' },
          { title: 'Grade' },
        ],
      });
```

Comment: The documentation in your own link is very comprehensive. This is the section you should reference: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - yes I see the issue is my JavaScript array is not in the format expected.  How do I manipulate my array data to mirror the needed format?

Comment: "_it gives error_" - what error?

Comment: Yes, you do have an array of objects - which is totally fine for DataTables to consume, as long as the column references match the JavaScript data. Show us the contents of your JavaScript `testData` variable, as text, and ideally as part of a [mre]. (The link in the comments is for an array of arrays - which is different from what you have. But you don't need to convert your array of objects into an array of arrays.)

Comment: Basically, you were on the right lines except you used `{ title: 'Name' }` in your DataTable definition, whereas you should have used `{ data: 'Name' }`. See [columns.title](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title) vs. [columns.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

and [Forums](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/96967/#Comment_96967)

You need

```
columns: [
  { data: 'Name' },
  { data: 'Grade' },
]
```

using your data

```js
const dataSet = [
 { Name: "Jason", Grade: 12 },
 { Name: "Mike", Grade: 11 },
 { Name: "Freddie", Grade: 10 }]
 
$(function () {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
      { data: 'Name' },
      { data: 'Grade' },
    ],
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Or THIS when converting to nested arrays

```js
const yourArray = [
 { Name: "Jason", Grade: 12 },
 { Name: "Mike", Grade: 11 },
 { Name: "Freddie", Grade: 10 }]
 
 const dataSet = yourArray.map(({Name,Grade}) => [Name,Grade])
$(function () {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
      { title: 'Name' },
      { title: 'Grade' },
    ],
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: understood what is needed.  How do I alter my data to meet the requirements?

Comment: That's what this code is doing, modifying your data in to the right format

Comment: Even better, I managed to do it with your data